# Why can't save uri object while building a uri?

Tags: java, android, uri

The first snippet won't append the 'locationQuery' paramenter, but the second one will, why the difference?

First snippet:

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL);
builtUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, locationQuery)
        .build();
```

Second snippet (From udacity course [github](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Sunshine/blob/6ca736c2395e1893e9dc82373141a38342e78238/S02.01-Solution-Networking/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/utilities/NetworkUtils.java#L73)):

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                  .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, locationQuery)
                  .build();
```

Comment: A `Builder` doesn't modify the existing `Uri`. The `Builder#build()` method _returns_ the new `Uri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not assigning Uri created with below expression

```
builtUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, locationQuery)
        .build();
```

Change it to

```
builtUri = builtUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, locationQuery)
        .build();
```